# Using WHERE clause to only retrieve results where array field has only ONE element inside

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table with various arrays within it like this:

```
{10574664,10574665,10574679,10574724}
{8616204,10574643,10574644,10574645,10574651,10574688,10574690,10574696,10574708}
{8616208}
{9830397}
{8616203}
{8616204,10574643,10574644,10574645,10574651,10574688,10574690,10574696,10574708}
{8616204,10574643,10574644,10574645,10574651,10574688,10574690,10574696,10574708}
{8616208}
{10574680}
{8616203}
```

Is there a way to only pull back the records where there is only one element in the array.
The results would look like this:

```
{8616208}
{9830397}
{8616203}
{8616208}
{10574680}
{8616203}
```

My query would look something like this

`Select * from attr_lookup where target_tcode =` **help with query here**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_length()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE):

```
SELECT *
FROM   attr_lookup
WHERE  array_length(target_tcode, 1) = 1;
```

Comment: That was easy. Thank you. -- Will accept answer when it lets me (after 10 minutes)